# create a histogram with female sex for two groups in ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, geom-bar

I want to create a histogram that presents the proportion of females (y axis) for each age group (x-axis). I want to have two bars for each age group that represent females with disease "N" and without disease "N".

Data:

[image: example data]

Other posts related to this topic that I have reviewed:

[r percentage by bin in histogram ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744111/r-percentage-by-bin-in-histogram-ggplot)

[Barplots with multiple factor groupings and mean of variable across those factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626350/barplots-with-multiple-factor-groupings-and-mean-of-variable-across-those-factor)

Code I have tried:

```
ggplot(N_group, aes(x=Age_2, fill=Sex))+
  geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
  geom_text(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], 
label=scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]) ),
            stat="count", position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5)
```

This compares males and females that have disease "N".

Comment: have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Reason, the asked Q is not reproducible. Please do not post screenshots of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Here, a possible solution is to calculate proportions out of `ggplot2`.

Here, an example using the following fake dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:40,
                 N = sample(c(0,1),40,replace = TRUE),
                 age_group = sample(1:4,40, replace = TRUE),
                 sex = sample(c("M","F"),40,replace = TRUE))
```

Using `dplyr` package, you can calculate proportion of each N group for each age_group for each gender:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  #group_by(sex, age_group, N, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  count(sex, age_group, N) %>% 
  filter(sex =="F") %>%
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  mutate(Percent = n / sum(n))


# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   age_group [4]
  sex   age_group     N     n Percent
  <fct>     <int> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1 F             1     0     1   0.167
2 F             1     1     5   0.833
3 F             2     0     2   0.4  
4 F             2     1     3   0.6  
5 F             3     0     2   0.4  
6 F             3     1     3   0.6  
7 F             4     0     1   0.5  
8 F             4     1     1   0.5
```

Passing this pipe sequence to `ggplot2` give you the following graph:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  count(sex, age_group, N) %>% 
  filter(sex =="F") %>%
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  mutate(Percent = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age_group, y = Percent, fill = factor(N)))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks @dc37  I get this error with your code (both with your data and mine) Error in count(., sex, age_group, N) : unused argument (N)

Comment: Weird, because with my example, I don't have this issue. Everything runs smoothly. Can you show the output of `str(df)` ?